Calculating the probabilities of getting each placement in a 32 player tournament in bracket style (single-elimination style)
pretty new to calculating probabilities so I need someone to verify my solution.
In the tournament we have a total of 32 players, and the tournament is played in single-elimination (participants compete in pairs and the loser of each round gets eliminated). Since there are 32 players, that means the most rounds a player can play is 5 (this being 1st and 2nd place). Assuming each players has an equal probability of winning each round my calculations are as follows (answered in decimals):
Probability of Placing 1st = (0.5)^5
Probability of Placing 2nd = (0.5)^4
Probability of placing 3rd - 4th = (0.5)^3
Probability of placing 5th - 8th = (0.5)^2
Probability of placing 9th - 32nd = 0.5
Is my logic correct?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Aside from the lack of formatting, it's not clear what you are trying to compute.  If each game is modeled as a coin toss (probability $\frac 12$, independent of all other games), then the rankings are uniformly distributed.  That is, each player is equally likely to win or to come in second.  Is that what you are asking?

No, what you are saying is not quite correct.

Out of $32$ players, $16$ (we don't know which $16$) will lose in Round $1$ with $Pr = \frac12$ each, and $16$ will progress to Round $2$, again with $Pr =\frac12$ each

Similarly, $8$ will win  round $2$, $8$ will lose round $2$ with $Pr = \frac14$ each


You can proceed like this round by round
Note particularly that in the finals, one player will win, one will lose, both with $Pr =(\frac12)^5 = \frac1{32}$ since both would have played $5$ matches with even odds.

Nice! I knew something was bugging me when I read OP's description. :)

Ahh okay, I think I get what you mean. Please correct me if I'm wrong so that means the probability is as follows:
1st - 2nd place = 1/32
3rd - 4th place = 1/16
5th - 8th place = 1/8
9th - 16th place = 1/4
17th - 32nd place = 1/2

Yes, that is right Only, remember, these rankings you are giving are after the results are out, because  initially,  you say that all  matches  have even odds.

Alright, thank you!

You're welcome ! ! $;;$ :)
